# filterable is not working for grid if i am apply if else condition in grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-ui-grid

if we apply if else condition in Kendo grid column then filterable not working for that particular column

```
{
                        field: " ", title: "Compliance Status", width: "180px",
                        template: "# if(WithinDueDt == 'Y'){# Completed on time #} else if(Ongoing == 'Y'){# Ongoing #} else if(CompletedbutDelayed == 'Y'){# Completed but Delayed #} else if(OngoingbutDelayed == 'Y'){# Ongoing but Delayed #} #"
 }
```

Comment: please  suggest solution for fix this

Comment: Try creating a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then we'll better understand your issue.

Comment: What's the model of your column? How are you declaring the filterable? (Those are key questions that a minimal, complete, reproducible example would answer.)

Comment: column modal is field , title and template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo Grid sorting and filtering functionality works based on the `field` value not based on the `template` value.
Here there is no field mapped to the column, so it is not working.

To resolve this issue: Pass the complianceStatus value from backend instead of writing template in grid.

Create a `String` field in the object and set value to that field based on the above conditions and then map that field in the grid, template not required.

For example if you are using java as backend:

```
private String complianceStatus;

private String getComplianceStatus(){

    complianceStatus = "";
    if(WithinDueDt == "Y"){  complianceStatus = "Completed on time" }
    else if(Ongoing == "Y"){ complianceStatus = "Ongoing" } 
    else if(CompletedbutDelayed == "Y"){complianceStatus = "Completed but Delayed"}
    else if(OngoingbutDelayed == "Y"){complianceStatus = "Ongoing but Delayed"}
    return complianceStatus ;

}
```

And in grid column:

```
{ field: "complianceStatus", title: "Compliance Status", width: "180px" }
```