# Kendo grid title without field in kendo jquery

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

how to show title without using field in kendo jquery

```
title: "Action",
filterable: false,
template: "#if( RefType == 'TASK'){ # <a class='btn-link anc' onclick='OpenChangeDetailsModal(RefId,'N')' >Create Task </a > #} else if(RefType == 'TEMPLATE'){# <a class='btn-link anc' onclick='OpenChangeDetailsModal(TaskTemplateId,'Y')' >Create Task </a > #}#"
```

Comment: give us some more explaination what you are trying to do

Comment: "title" refers to what? Column title? Please edit you question with more code from the grid and maybe a screen of the result you expect.

Comment: Like I said in other post of yours, You need to map field.
[filterable-is-not-working-for-grid-if-i-am-apply-if-else-condition-in-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56479933/8733214)